# How do I make a running total of a variable that changes in JavaScript due to live data?

Tags: javascript

I need to measure how long the following code calls the vibrate function in seconds and display the seconds which I have working. However, I don't know how to create a running total so that every time vibrate() is called, it both measures the length in seconds and then adds this to a running total.

```
function goodValue() {
    startTime = new Date()
    string1 = 'GOOD!!! :)'
    displayValue('Angles', string1)
}

var startTime = {}
function badValue() {
    var endTime = new Date()
    vibrate1(1500)
    string2 = 'BAD!!! :('
    displayValue('Angles', string2)
    var timeDiff = endTime - startTime //in ms
    // strip the ms
    timeDiff /= 1000

    // get seconds 
    seconds = Math.round(timeDiff);
    displayValue('TotalTime', + seconds);
}
```

Comment: Create a variable which holds the running total, and add to it on every call.

Answer (score 0):

This should now work. It's assuming that you call `goodAngle()` when the app recognizes a good angle, and `badAngle()` when the app recognizes a bad angle.

```js
var totalTime = 0
var startTime = false

function goodAngle() {
  if (startAngle) {
    timeDiff = (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000
    console.log('timeDiff: %s seconds', timeDiff)
    totalTime += timeDiff
    console.log('total timeDiff: %s seconds', timeDiff)
    string1 = 'GOOD!!! :)'
    displayValue('Angles', string1)
    displayValue('BadPostureTime', Math.round(timeDiff))
    startTime = false // So it  can't be called again unless there's a badAngle first
  }
}

function badAngle() {
  if (!startTime) {
    // Only set startTime if there isn't a current timer running
    startTime = Date.now()
    vibrate1(1500)
    string2 = 'BAD!!! :('
    displayValue('Angles', string2)
  }
}
```

Comment: No. Every time I run it, it just keeps counting the seconds from 0 upwards instead of giving me a total of seconds.

Comment: I did and it's the same result.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what your code does? When are goodValue() and badValue() called, and what time do you want your running total to represent? The time between goodValue and badValue?

Comment: It's an app that measures angles. If the angle is bad, then the mobile device vibrates until the user corrects the angle and measures how many seconds the angle was bad. What I need to do is have the total amount of time the user held the phone at the bad angle for over the course of a set amount of time, like one hour. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It tells me the number of seconds the angle was bad... but then once the angle is corrected, the value of seconds is wiped? I've tried reassigning to another variable but it hasn't worked.

Comment: @user11012592 I just updated my answer, see if that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what your code is supposed to do but I would advise making
a function which would wrap around your vibrate1 implementation.
The measureTime function takes a function as an argument (in your case vibrate) and
returns a function which has a property `totalTime` that records the execution
time. Note that it uses `performance.now()` instead of a `Date` object. See
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Performance/now for reference.

```
function measureTime(fn) {
  const returnedFn = function measuredFunction (arg) {
    const start = performance.now();
    fn(arg);
    const end = performance.now();
    returnedFn.totalTime = returnedFn.totalTime + ((end - start) / 1000); 
  };
  returnedFn.totalTime = 0;

  return returnedFn;
}

const measuredVibrate = measureTime(vibrate1);


displayValue(measuredVibrate.totalTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Skip to the expanded code snippet for the answer to this question. The rest of the examples address measuring other related metrics.*

### Measuring Each Individual Time

If you want to measure a function's execution time, you can wrap it in another function that uses [`console.time()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) and [`console.timeEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd):

```js
function measure (fn, label = fn.name) {
  return function () {
    try {
      console.time(label)
      return fn.apply(this, arguments)
    } finally {
      console.timeEnd(label)
    }
  }
}

function delay (ms) {
  const now = Date.now()

  while (Date.now() - now < ms) { }
}

// wrap the function that needs to be tested
const timedDelay = measure(delay)

timedDelay(100)
timedDelay(10)
```

This `measure()` function has a few nice features:

- The original function's return value is always preserved
- The original function's thrown error is always preserved
- If the original function throws an error, the time taken is still logged
- The optional `label` argument is used to label the time that appears in the console
- The `label` defaults to the name of the original function
- The original function receives the context and arguments exactly as they were passed

To measure asynchronous functions, you can use the following, which can handle concurrent calls by incrementing a number used within the `label` in addition to the features above:

```js
function measureAsync (fn, name = fn.name) {
  let index = 0

  return async function () {
    const label = `${name} (${++index})`

    try {
      console.time(label)
      return await fn.apply(this, arguments)
    } finally {
      console.timeEnd(label)
    }
  }
}

function delay (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
}

// wrap the async function that needs to be tested
const timedDelay = measureAsync(delay)

timedDelay(1000)
timedDelay(100)
timedDelay(500)
```

### Measuring Total Time

Using the above two implementations, you can modify them with the [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) to measure cumulative time instead:

#### Synchronous

```js
function measureTotal (fn, label = fn.name) {
  return Object.assign(function measured () {
    try {
      performance.mark(label)
      return fn.apply(this, arguments)
    } finally {
      performance.measure(label, label)
      const [{ duration }] = performance.getEntriesByName(label, 'measure')
      const total = measured.total += duration
      performance.clearMarks(label)
      performance.clearMeasures(label)
      console.log(`${label}: ${total.toFixed(3)}ms`)
    }
  }, {
    total: 0
  })
}

function delay (ms) {
  const now = Date.now()

  while (Date.now() - now < ms) { }
}

// wrap the function that needs to be tested
const timedDelay = measureTotal(delay)

timedDelay(100)
timedDelay(10)
timedDelay(50)

console.log('total:', timedDelay.total)
```

#### Asynchronous

```js
function measureTotalAsync (fn, name = fn.name) {
  let index = 0

  return Object.assign(async function measured () {
    const label = `${name} (${++index})`

    try {
      performance.mark(label)
      return await fn.apply(this, arguments)
    } finally {
      performance.measure(label, label)
      const [{ duration }] = performance.getEntriesByName(label, 'measure')
      const total = measured.total += duration
      performance.clearMarks(label)
      performance.clearMeasures(label)
      console.log(`${label}: ${total.toFixed(3)}ms`)
    }
  }, {
    total: 0
  })
}

function delay (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
}

// wrap the async function that needs to be tested
const timedDelay = measureTotalAsync(delay)

Promise.all([
  timedDelay(1000),
  timedDelay(100),
  timedDelay(500)
]).finally(() => {
  console.log('total:', timedDelay.total)
})
```

### References

- [`performance.mark()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/mark)
- [`performance.measure()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure)
- [`performance.getEntriesByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByName)